What is Collateral swap? How to get benefits from this feature?
Let's say ETH price is $3,000 and wstETH price is $3,500.
I have collateral using ETH on Aave.
and tomorrow ETH price is $2,950 and wstETH price is $3,650.
I did swap my collateral from ETH to wstETH.
So, how I'm getting profit from this? Where is my profit after collateral swap is done? Can I withdraw the profit? Can I use flashloan to liquidate myself and get the profit?
